# Attach GDB to Qemu running different kernels on each smp

Tags: gdb, qemu, gdbserver

How do I attach `gdb` to ARM Qemu board with each smp running different kernels? When I use `gdb` options, I can only specify one kernel with the `file` option in `gdb`.

Qemu Command :

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -smp 2 \
-display none -nographic \
-device loader,file=f1.axf,cpu-num=0 \
-device loader,file=f2.axf,cpu-num=1 -s -S
```

`gdb` commands ran:

```
gdb-multiarch
target remote localhost:1234
file f1.axf
```

After this, `gdb` shows two threads, both showing debug source as `f1.axf`.

If I pass `f2.axf` in file option, both thread show source and debug info from `f2.axf`.

There is no error message from `gdb`

Setup:

- Host: Ubuntu 18.04, 64bits
- Guest: Qemu Arm
- GDB Multiarch: Running on Host machine(Ubuntu)

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please edit your question and add the `gdb` call statement(s) you have tried so far together with the error message or short description what didn't work. Please also clarify your setup: Where is `gdb` running, where is the host with the process under debugging executed, how does your `Qemu` setup look alike...

Comment: Tried to add info according to your comment, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Just a guess: Use two terminals and open `gdb` in each terminal to connect to `f1.axf` in one terminal and `f2.axf` in the other terminal?

Comment: But I can connect through only one GDB as only one gdbserver is present. Other GDB can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add each smp cpu as an Arm Cpucluster in my Qemu board file. Make sure that you assign different cluster index to each cpu, else they will attach to same GDB. So for N number of clusters, you can attach N gdbs. After that gdb can be attached to Qemu listening on port 1234, using following commands:

```
gdb-multiarch
target extended :1234
file f1.axf
add-inferior
inferior 2
attach 2
file f2.axf
info thread
```

Add as many inferiors as many cpu clusters you have. To attach to cluster 4, add command `attach 4` in gdb.